# DOCUSIGN API - How to use same account for multiple users

Tags: docusignapi

I have docusign demo account (i am admin) and have added few users as admin users. I have created c# web api project and using docusign REST apis internally (goal is to send envelope for signing). While using my integration key, RSA key  application passing without any issue. I have hardcoded the keys in app.config.

I want to use the same account for other added users in my application. For that what i have to accomplish? The envelope should carry the sending user name in mail rather than my name (admin).

i have tried to use their account id with my integration key but getting consent_required error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly: you have a working app with JWT Grant authentication.

You want to use (test) your app with other envelope senders.

Answer: As Inbar says, part of using the JWT Grant authentication flow is the `Impersonated User GUID`. Your application can use any user's guid, including users from any account (on demo).

When your application uses a guid for the first time, your app will receive the `consent_required` error.

To eliminate the error, the user must grant consent to your application. See [comment 1](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/issues/111#issuecomment-513537950) and [comment 2](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/issues/118#issuecomment-513538413) for the techniques to do so.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign has accounts and account is usually for an organization or a group. Inside accounts we have users. Each account has an id (either GUID or short number) and each user has an id - always a GUID. It seems you are using JWT auth which allows you to make API calls on behalf of other users if they consented to this app doing so at least once. You can log in as this user once to give consent to that application.